# Oracle DB query data_length(what's it return)

Tags: java, database, oracle

I am running some queries on an Oracle DB from my java program. Once a certain table is selected this query runs and returns some traits for the user.

A simplified version of my code  as follows.

```
String query = "SELECT column_name, data_type, data_length FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'blahblah'";
String ColumnName;
String DataType;
String DataLength;

System.out.println(ColumName);
System.out.println(DataType);
System.out.println(DataLength);
```

I am unsure as to what `data_length` is returning.

Is it returning the length of the data in the field? Or is it returning the max value. After some searching I have come across conflicting opinions. And when comparing the data type I get with its associated length it seems that it could be the max length but who knows maybe the field is just maxed out?

For Example:

`Data Type = Number` is returning `Data Length = 22`

`Data Type = VARCHAR2` is returning `Data Length = 2000`

*Bonus: (+5 points on final grade, and 1 free absence from class)*

*How could I change the query to get the data I dont have. (actual data length, or max data length).*

Comment: Hahaha ouch. Despite my clever wording(which I found hilarious) of my own bonus question this is not homework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be relatively easy to test.  Note that there is no `ALL_TABLE_COLUMNS` view-- there is an `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` and an `ALL_TAB_COLS` view that provide this information.  I'll create an empty table and run the query I assume your professor intended.

```
SQL> create table empty_table (
  2    col1 number(10,2),
  3    col2 varchar2(100),
  4    col3 varchar2(100 byte),
  5    col4 varchar2(100 char)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>   select column_name, data_type, data_length
  2      from all_tab_columns
  3     where table_name = 'EMPTY_TABLE'
  4  order by column_name;

COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_TYPE      DATA_LENGTH
------------------------------ -------------- -----------
COL1                           NUMBER                  22
COL2                           VARCHAR2               100
COL3                           VARCHAR2               100
COL4                           VARCHAR2               300
```

Now that you've seen the actual result, it should be clear what length is being returned in the `DATA_LENGTH` column.

Comment: ahh correct, my actualy code uses all_tab I will edit. Guess I had a moment haha.

Comment: I think Ive got it, so just to be clear between the two answers, it is the maximum allowed amount the field can hold? Not the max amount it was created with?

Comment: @harper89 - I'm not sure what you mean by "the max amount it was created with".  `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` tells you the declared maximum size the column was created with.  It tells you nothing about the data that was inserted in that column after the table was created.

Comment: I was referring to the other answer. That is what I need then, Just need to know the max that is allowed not what is there already. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should represent the length that column was created with.

i.e. numbers default to 22, but you may override that NUMBER(5) or something.
varchar2 (4000) etc.

In order to find the actual max length of the values contained in the column, you need to query the table itself, not the data dictionary.

```
SELECT max( len( mycol )) from mytab;
```

there may be some statistics gathered for these things, but that may not be reliable for your application.

Comment: "numbers default to 22, but you may override that NUMBER(5)" Data length is not precision. `create table t (n number(5));` `select column_name, data_length from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'T';` gives back a data length of 22.